# How would i put this code into a re-usable function?

Tags: javascript, function

I found this code on stackoverflow that fades out an audio track slowly. It works well. It is structured in a way that i find very difficult to re-use without copy and pasting because the function calls itself within itself. Here is the code:

```
function fadeVolume(volume, callback) {
    //change the volume by factor each time
    //will check if setTimeout is used to loop as well as wait, as it seems so here
    var factor = 0.02,
        speed = 50;
    if (volume > factor) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            fadeVolume((gameController.myAudio.preGameTrack.volume -= factor), callback);
        }, speed);
    } else {
        (typeof (callback) !== 'function') || callback();
    }
};
fadeVolume(gameController.myAudio.preGameTrack.volume, function () {
    preGameContent.ready = true;
    //stop the music altogether
    gameController.myAudio.preGameTrack.pause();
    gameController.myAudio.preGameTrack.currentTime = 0;
})
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you having trouble saving it to a file and using `<script>` tags, or...?

Comment: So you want to use iterations instead of recursion

Comment: There are libraries for tweening, the tweening part is reusable and what is tweened is application specific

Comment: It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: fadeVolume is not defined " because it hasn't yet been made and i'm calling it. I want to put this function inside an object called preGameContent and call it from any places that i may want to fade a track. preGameContent.fadeVolume(...);

Answer (score 2):

Every statement will remain except the `gameController.myAudio.preGameTrack` .

Store that in a variable and pass in.. Should be reusable if you are talking in that context.

```
function fadeVolume(track, factor, speed, callback) {
    //change the volume by factor each time
    //will check if setTimeout is used to loop as well as wait, as it seems so here

    if (track.volume > factor) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            fadeVolume((track.volume -= factor), callback);
        }, speed);
    } else {
        (typeof (callback) !== 'function') || callback();
    }
};

var track = gameController.myAudio.preGameTrack,
    factor = 0.2,
    speed = 50;
fadeVolume(track, factor, speed, function () {
    preGameContent.ready = true;
    //stop the music altogether
    track.pause();
    track.currentTime = 0;
})
```

Comment: It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: fadeVolume is not defined " because it hasn't yet been made and i'm calling it. I want to put this function inside an object called preGameContent and call it from any places that i may want to fade a track. preGameContent.fadeVolume(...);